# Does the empty set permit zero or one equivalence classes?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $\varnothing$ (it must in fact be the empty relation). Does $\varnothing\big/\sim$ have no elements, or one, namely $\varnothing$? Put differently, does $\varnothing$ get partioned into one equivalence class, namely $\varnothing,$ or no equivalence classes, because equivalence classes are defined relative to elements of the original set, of which there are none?

I think the answer is the latter, i.e., there are *no* equivalence classes, because equivalence classes cannot be empty by definition. But I must admit, even after checking the [definitions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Equivalence_class), I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Remark: in mathematics, to preserve the correspondence between equivalence relations and partitions, we define partitions to be sets of non-empty sets. In computer science, it is common to allow partitions to include the empty set. So for (some) computer scientists, $\emptyset$ has two partitions, while for (most) mathematicians it has only one. The two communities agree that there is only one equivalence relation on the empty set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, then $$X/{\sim} = \{[x]\mid x\in X\},$$ where $[x] = \{y\in X\mid x\sim y\}$ is the equivalence class of $x$. When $X$ is empty, there is no $x\in X$, so there are no equivalence classes: $$\varnothing/{\sim} = \{[x]\mid x\in \varnothing\} = \varnothing.$$

Answer (score 2):

Equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on a set $A$ are non-empty subsets of $A$. If $A=\emptyset$, there are no non-empty subsets, hence no equivalence classes. In other words $$\emptyset /{\sim}=\emptyset.$$